# unattend.xml - Make non-admin user auto-logged in by default

Tags: windows, automation, hyper-v, unattend-file

```
 <UserAccounts>
    <LocalAccounts>
        <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
            <Password>
                <Value>YQBkAG0AaQBuAGEAZABtAGkAbgBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQA</Value>
                <PlainText>false</PlainText>
            </Password>
            <Description>user</Description>
            <DisplayName>admin</DisplayName>
            <Group>Administrators</Group>
            <Name>admin</Name>
        </LocalAccount>
        <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
            <Password>
                <Value>dQBzAGUAcgB1AHMAZQByAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                <PlainText>false</PlainText>
            </Password>
            <DisplayName>user</DisplayName>
            <Group>Users</Group>
            <Name>user</Name>
        </LocalAccount>
    </LocalAccounts>
</UserAccounts>
<AutoLogon>
    <Password>
        <Value>dQBzAGUAcgB1AHMAZQByAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
        <PlainText>false</PlainText>
    </Password>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <LogonCount>1000</LogonCount>
    <Username>user</Username>
</AutoLogon>
```

Using the component for autologon in the System Image Manager doesn't seem to let me autologin as the default user w/the credentials I set. I assume there's something small I'm overlooking to why this is the case. I know since I'm testing this in a VM, I'm getting kickback on the user login that I have to add it to the 'Remote Desktop Users' before it'll let me log in at all, but I don't think that would stop the autologon option from being enabled entirely? I guess that's possible?

I tried setting the component up in the way that looks correct, I guess. Seems like it should work, unless setting up auto-login as a non-admin is just not possible. If not, is it possible to set-up autologin for an admin named 'user', then have a post-logon script that changes their group to Users?

Also, this deployment will eventually be attached to a domain - I think I've read that auto-logon is not possible on a domain-joined device, even if the logged in account is purely local?